# Private method and encapsulation : Prevent accidental private method overriding

Tags: ruby, encapsulation

I am currently trying to understand how the encapsulation mechanism works in Ruby :

```
class A
    def public_method_A; p private_method; end;
    private
    def private_method; 'A'; end;
end

class B < A
    def public_method_B; p private_method; end;
    private
    def private_method; 'B'; end;
end
```

Now when I try to run this code, here is what I get :

```
1. > A.new.public_method_A => "A"
2. > B.new.public_method_B => "B"
3. > B.new.public_method_A => "B"
```

Basically, the third call refers to the private method defined in B and not in A. From a Java developer's point of view, it is an encapsulation violation. The call to `private_method` should always refer to the method defined in the class where the call is made. However in Ruby, it seems that it is more a matter of context. Is this right ?

How can I make sure that my private methods are never called outside their respective class ? Am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Nutshell: `private` means the message can't have an explicit receiver.

That's all; nothing more.

It removes the message from the public API, but does nothing regarding subclasses and so on.

`protected` means only instances and sub-class instances can call the method, e.g., you can't call it from outside the inheritance tree.

Note that both are trivially subverted via `send`.

[Nice summary of `private` and `protected` in Ruby](http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/05/20/private-and-protected-they-might-not-mean-what-you-think-they-mean/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is still not clear to me how I can encapsulate those methods ? How those classes should be organized considering this problem ? Using modules ? or maybe by applying the behaviours dynamically ?

Comment: @FrancisToth Encapsulate meaning what? I don't find this a problem, but it depends on your use case. If your goal is to prevent extension, but go beyond what the language semantics allow, you could maybe use the subclassing hooks. I'd be careful about the ROI though.